# Cannot open second window, Event loop already running - PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am currently trying to get a button press in one qt window to open a second window which is in another python file. My layout code was generated by converting a ui made in Qt designer to python.

My select feature code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'movie_design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import add_entry


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(597, 522)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 40, 291, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLineWidth(1)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 110, 261, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 230, 261, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 350, 261, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 597, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMenu.setObjectName("menuMenu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.add)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Movie Database Program"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete Record"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add Record"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search Records"))
        self.menuMenu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu"))

    def add(self):
        add_entry.add_entry()



def main():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, I have created a button that when pressed calls the function in the program "add_entry.py"

Add entry.py code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'add_entry.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(555, 418)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 533, 28))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 501, 321))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.MovieTitle = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.MovieTitle.setObjectName("MovieTitle")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.MovieTitle)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.MovieStudio = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.MovieStudio.setObjectName("MovieStudio")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.MovieStudio)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.dateEdit)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.ProductionCost = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.ProductionCost.setMaximum(1000000000)
        self.ProductionCost.setObjectName("ProductionCost")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.ProductionCost)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_6)
        self.BoxOfficeRevenue = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.BoxOfficeRevenue.setMaximum(1000000000)
        self.BoxOfficeRevenue.setObjectName("BoxOfficeRevenue")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.BoxOfficeRevenue)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_7)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.No = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.No.setFont(font)
        self.No.setObjectName("No")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.No)
        self.Yes = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Yes.setFont(font)
        self.Yes.setObjectName("Yes")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Yes)
        self.formLayout.setLayout(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.horizontalLayout)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_8)
        self.classificationBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.classificationBox.setFont(font)
        self.classificationBox.setObjectName("classificationBox")
        self.classificationBox.addItem("")
        self.classificationBox.addItem("")
        self.classificationBox.addItem("")
        self.classificationBox.addItem("")
        self.classificationBox.addItem("")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.classificationBox)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.formLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt; text-decoration: underline;\">Add Entry</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Movie Title"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Movie Studio"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Release Date"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Production Cost (m$)"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Box Office Revenue (m$)"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Have you seen this movie?"))
        self.No.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Yes"))
        self.Yes.setText(_translate("Dialog", "No"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Classification (Age Rating)"))
        self.classificationBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "U"))
        self.classificationBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "PG"))
        self.classificationBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "12"))
        self.classificationBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "15"))
        self.classificationBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "18"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Add Entry"))


def add_entry():  
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_entry()
```

The issue is that the when the button is pressed, the program crashes, telling me that "Event loop already running". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt, like many GUI frameworks, is based on an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) which is started with `app.exec_()` and then waits for events to react to (both from the user or the system).
For each Qt program there should always be a single and only QApplication instance running its event loop.

With your implementation, each time you press the button, you're trying to create and launch a new QApplication, and Qt will not allow you for the reason above.

Nonetheless, the problem with your code is somewhere else, as you are using the generated UI code in the wrong way: those files should **never** be used as a basis to create your program code (in fact, you should always leave them as they are).
I suggest you to carefully read the official documentation about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand how to use those files.

Regenerate the UI files with pyuic, and then create a *new* script that will probably contain something similar to this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from ui_dialog import Ui_Dialog

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.add)

    def add(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        dialog.exec_()


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this example I used the third method (multiple inheritance approach) explained in the documentation given above.